Solana too many requests
I want to send multiple transactions, and I am using multiple recent block hashes in my code. With some time public RPCs get exhausted. Are there good alternatives for doing something like 100 API calls per second, or any other good approach?

If the rate limits on the public RPC nodes are too restrictive for your use-case, you'll need to setup your own RPC node, either through a node provider or on your own.
